# How can I modify yaml instructions outside of the document I am rendering

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'd like to `rmarkdown::render` a `R` document without indicating the yaml options **within the document itself**.

Ideally that could be an argument on `rmarkdown::render` or `knitr::spin` like what you can do to pass `params` (see the [Rmarkdown reference book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-knit.html)). Typically I'd like `author`, `date` and the `output` options too.

I think this is possible because spining the [following document](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yihui/knitr/master/inst/examples/knitr-spin.R) without specifying anything I get the following output (so there must be a template of default args that I can hopefully change)

---

[image]

---

As an example, how could I do to `render` a document that would give me the same output as say the below (**but of course without specifying the yaml in the document ie no yaml whatsoever in the document**)

```
---
title: "Sample Document"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    theme: united
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    highlight: zenburn
---

#' # Title
Hello world

#+ one_plus_one
1 + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `cat` a `sink` into a `tempfile`.

```
xxx <- "
#' # Title
Hello world

#+ one_plus_one
1 + 1
"

tmp <- tempfile()
sink(tmp)
cat("
---
title: 'Sample Document'
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    theme: united
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    highlight: zenburn
---", xxx)
sink()
w.d <- getwd()
rmarkdown::render(tmp, output_file=paste(w.d, "myfile", sep="/"))
```

Comment: hum yes I could actually build the entire yaml like this, it's good idea

Comment: Or check option keep .tex file in RStudio, exploit the code of a sample and use [in_header](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/yaml-options.html) option somehow, perhaps combined with my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass yaml options as parameters too. For example:

```
---
params: 
  title: "add title"
  author: "add author"
output: pdf_document
title: "`r params$title`"
author: "`r params$author`"
---

This is my document text.
```

Then, in a separate R script:

```
rmarkdown::render("my_doc.rmd", 
                  params=list(title="My title", 
                              author="eipi10"))
```

Comment: Yes +1 , I knew that, but what I want is to have **NO** yaml block in the document, sorry if that was not clear enough

Comment: How could this work for params$output? It is not a string and I think it is causing me troubles at getting it from `params$`